# Splash screen in IOS does not display

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi 10.4.1 with the latest patches. iOS 14.2 SDK using XCode 12.x (latest in app store).
MacOS Big Sur (if it matters)

The splash screen works perfectly in Android.

However, in iOS, it does not work.  I created a new project... splash shows
in Android but there is a 1-3 seconds show of a white screen then the simple
app appears (it's a template app from Delphi Wizard).

I have googled but it seems people hardly has this problem.

I set the background
of the IOS splash to different bright colours to see if the splash indeed comes out in these
colours but it didn't show these bright backgrounds, or the standard FM splash screen.

For the Android, there's a checkbox to say [x] Show splash  but there is nothing
for IOS.  So I assume that IOS does not need a setting to show the splash screen?

This happens whether I use the default FireMonkey splash screens, or provide my own
(in the same dimensions)

Please advise.

Comment: You might want to check out this report, and the links in my comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31840

Comment: @DaveNottage  I had come across the thread you mentioned in the comment before. However, my situation is that the Splash (launch image) does not appear in the iOS app at all.  It just shows an all white screen for 1-2 seconds then it displays the app.  Compiling the samples from Delphi 10.4.1 also gave the same results.   XCode 12.2 latest in App Store. iOS SDK 14.2 with latest 10.4.1 Mac/IOS patches.

Comment: Was the project created in a version of Delphi 10.3.3 or earlier? If so, delete the info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml file (if you haven't customised it) and allow the IDE to recreate it.

Comment: @DaveNottage yes, project was created earlier. the sample projects from Delphi were from 10.4.1 though.  Your solution worked great! much appreciated. If you could post it as an answer, I'll up-vote it and mark it as the right answer. Thanks once again!